# Using group and indexed max together

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

**Code:**

```
r.db('dealdb').table('messages')
    .filter({ dealId : request.dealId })
    .group('conversationId')
    .max({ index: 'sendDate' })
    .ungroup()
    .getField('reduction')
```

**Error:**

```
Expected type TABLE but found SEQUENCE
```

So my understanding is that `group` returns a sequence while `max` expects a table.

However, `max` without an index works as expected

```
r.db('dealdb').table('messages')
    .filter({ dealId : request.dealId })
    .group('conversationId')
    .max('sendDate')
    .ungroup()
    .getField('reduction')
```

So why does an indexed `max` not work in a sequence while a non-indexed `max` does? And how do I get this working with an indexed `max`

Answer (score 0):

`max` with index only works at table level. That means this will work:

```
r.db('dealdb').table('messages').max({ index: 'sendDate' })
```

but when we call on a stream or a selection, we cannot use index anymore.
That's why it won't work as you see.

Without `index` options, we can call `max` on any arrays, streams, selections, and tables.